# Is there a way to continuously print a live timestamp to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pyautogui

I have this code, which looks for a specific image continously. If it sees the image, I want it to write "Duck" followed by the current datetime into a csv file:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()

i = 1

f = open('ducklog.csv', 'a', newline=(''))
tup1 = ('Duck', now)
writer = csv.writer(f)



while i<=5:
    Got_him = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("That Duck.png")
    if Got_him == None:
        print (Got_him)
        continue

    else:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(Got_him)
        print("OH GOD THERE HE IS")
        print(now)
        writer.writerow(tup1)
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
```

This runs fine, but the issue I'm finding is that once the code finishes, it writes all of the lines to the csv simultaneously which means they all receive the **same** datetime value.

How can I have the datetime written into the csv iteratively, so that the times refect each individual datetime value that reflects when the image was actually seen?

Comment: Fix the indentation of the shown code.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I'm super new to python (you've probably guessed) but from trying to fix this before leaving a question this rings a bell - something to do with the fact we've got a loop going on and the writing action being part of it?

Could you show me at all? THANK-YOU FOR HELPING!

Comment: @mkrieger1 ahhh interesting, is this true even though I've included "now = datetime.datetime.now()" ahead of the writing action in the else: section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the indentation in your code, the issue is that you set `tup1` once at the beginning, rather than feeding it the time at which you find the duck. **Changing `now` later on, will not update the value in the tuple.**

Within your `else` block, you either have to update `tup1` giving it the new value for `now` or you get rid of `tup1` altogether:

```
...
now = datetime.datetime.now()  
tup1 = ('Duck',now)  
writer.writerow(tup1)
```

or (*in my opinion more readable*)

```
...
writer.writerow(('Duck', datetime.datetime.now()))
```

Comment: Absolutely nailed it, just got rid of Tup1 altogether. First time asking a question on here, this is magic - THANK YOU!!

Code is now working as I had hoped, is there still an issue with indentation, something I should tweak as a best-practice?

Comment: Maybe it is a formatting error when posting here, but in your 2nd line of the while loop there is an *if* and the print below it is not indented.

Comment: Ahh yep, just a formatting error in the question - good spot. THANKS!!